# Help with understanding the proof of $[a,b]$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, real-numbers

I am having trouble understanding certain parts of the proof of theorem 2 that my professor gave. Could someone kindly clarify these parts?

First, a theorem he used in the proof:

$\textbf{Theorem 1.}$ ($\textit{Nested Interval Theorem}$) If $\{I_n\}$ is a sequence of closed and bounded intervals in
$\mathbb{R}^1$
such that
$I_n \supseteq I_{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1$
then
$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset$.

Now, the proof:

$\textbf{Theorem 2.}$ Every closed interval $[a,b]$ is compact.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ Let $I = \{x \ |\ a \leq x \leq b \}$ and let $\delta = b-a$. Then $|x-y| \leq  \delta$ if $x,y \in I$.

Suppose there exists an open covering $\mathscr{G} = \{G_\alpha\}$ of $I$ which has no finite covering. Let $c= \frac{a+b}{2}$, so 
$I = [a,c] \cup [c,b]$.

At least one of these intervals cannot be covered by any finite subcover of $\mathscr{G}$; call it $I_1$. We next bisect $I_1$ and continue this process. We get a sequence $\{I_n \}$ of closed intervals such that

$(i)\ I_n \supseteq I_{n+1} \forall n \geq 1$;

$(ii)\ I_n$ is $\textbf{not}$ covered by any finite subcollection of $\mathscr{G}$;

$(iii)$ If $x,y \in I_n$, then $|x-y| \leq \frac{\delta}{2^n}$.

By Theorem 1, $\exists\ x^* \in$ each $I_n$. So $x^* \in$ some $G_\alpha$.

$\textbf{I don't understand this next line. Why must there exist such an r?}$

Since $G_\alpha$ is open, $\exists\ r > 0$ such that
$$|y-x^*|<r\ \Rightarrow\ y \in G_\alpha.$$

$\textbf{I also don't understand this next sentence. I am not seeing how n being so large implies}$ $(iii) \Rightarrow I_n \subseteq G_\alpha.$

If $n$ is so large that $\frac{\delta}{2^n} < r$ (there is such an $n$, for otherwise $2^n \leq \frac{\delta}{r}\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which is not possible becasue $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean), then $(iii)$ implies $I_n \subseteq G_\alpha$ which contradicts $(ii)$. $□$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why there is such an r.  Because that is the definition of open.  G is open so y is an interior point so there is a neighbor around y that is entirely in G.  So if the radius if the neighborhood is r, then anything within r from point y is in the neighborhood, which is a subset of G.

Comment: Why n large enough?  Because by the nested interval theorem xstar is in all I_n and the length of I_n is d/2^n.  So one of those I_n with length d/2^n < r is so short it fits right into that neighbor of xstar and is a subset of G.

Comment: I think that theorem 1 is false. For example you can take $I_n = [n, \infty)$

Comment: @ThePortakal Your $I_n$ is not closed so theorem 1 doesn't apply! (sorry for the super late response, I have been busy...)

Comment: @CuriousMathStudent In fact, they are closed (but not compact) intervals. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html

Comment: @ThePortakal Oh right! After checking my notes, it seems my professor didn't write $I_n$ also has to be bounded. So adding that condition, the theorem holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo on the line after (iii). It should read $``$So $x^*\in$ some $G_\alpha$$"$ instead of $``$$x^*\in$ each $G_\alpha$$"$.

Why must there exist such an $r$? This is because $x^*$ is an element of $G_\alpha$ which is an open set. So by definition there exists an open interval of some radius $r$ centered around $x^*$ and inside $G_\alpha$ i.e. $(x^*-r, x^*+r)\subset G_\alpha$ i.e., if $y\in (x^*-r, x^*+r)$ then $y\in G_\alpha$ and so $|y-x^*|<r\Rightarrow y\in G_\alpha$.

Now if $n$ is so large that $\frac{\delta}{2^n}<r$ then for $y\in I_n$, (by (iii)) $$|y-x^*|<\frac{\delta}{2^n}<r$$ which implies by above that $y\in G_\alpha$. So $I_n\subset G_\alpha$. This is a contradiction because by construction, $I_n$ is not supposed to be coverable by any finite subcollection of $\mathscr{G}$.

Comment: Yes. There is not necessarily any $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r)\subset G_a$ for all $a$.  It should say $\exists r>0\;\exists a\;(\;(x-r,x+r)\subset G_a\;).$

Answer (score 1):

1. That such an $r$ exists is directly from the definition of the [metric space topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence) in $\mathbb{R}$: Any open set $U$ in the real line is a union of sets $B(x, r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \, \, ; |x - y| < r\}$ running over $x \in U$ and some collection of numbers $r > 0$.
2. At some $n$ the set $I_n$ will be contained in the ball $B(x^*, r)$ because every $y \in I_n$ will be within $r$ of the point $x^*$ --- as described in the steps following your second question. In other words, every point $y \in I_n$ is a point of $B(x^*, r)$ which, using your previous assertion, is a point of $G_\alpha$.

That means some $I_n$ is contained in a single $G_\alpha$, which gives you the contradiction.